# Issue in Xamarin Installation

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms

I have installed Xamarin for Visual Studio 2013 and 2015. Setup says it is installed successfully but while creating the application a message box appears explaining the issue. Please see the image[image: Xamarin Issue while creating app]

Regards,
Manoj

Comment: What order did you install Xamarin and Visual Studio? Make sure you install VS first

Comment: I installed vs first and then went for xamarin for visual studio